# How to COPY a large Cassandra table without running out of memory?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am attempting to run a simple Cassandra database COPY script, like the example below (or some variation that is very similar):

```
COPY my_keyspace_name.my_table_name TO 'cassandra_dump/my_keyspace_name.my_table_name.csv' WITH HEADER=true AND PAGETIMEOUT=40 AND PAGESIZE=20 AND DELIMITER='|';
```

It works on most tables except my largest one. In that case I get an error where it cannot allocate enough memory. The file size of the table is nowhere near as large in data as the error message claims (less than 1GB).

> 749314 rows exported to 1 files in 9 minutes and 11.240 seconds.
>
> ./dump_cassandra.sh: xmalloc: ../../.././lib/sh/strtrans.c:63: cannot allocate 18446744072166431589 bytes (6442528768 bytes allocated)", "stdout_lines": ["[Thu May 17 13:41:47 UTC 2018] Executing the following query:", "COPY my_keyspace_name.my_table_name TO 'cassandra_dump/my_keyspace_name.my_table_name.csv' WITH HEADER=true AND PAGETIMEOUT=40 AND PAGESIZE=20 AND DELIMITER='|';"

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41465577/1475817) seemed promising, but unfortunately it does not work for me.

Is there something I am missing that is preventing me from running a successful COPY on a large (relatively speaking) table?

--

**EDIT:** This error seems to be environmental. I have had mixed results on different servers with nearly identical amounts of data.

Comment: Have you tried throttling the COPY command? Please see the link below: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html. I'm thinking at: NUMPROCESSES, CHUNKSIZE, MAXREQUESTS

Comment: What cassandra version?

Comment: Version is 2.1.17.1448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `MAXOUTPUTSIZE` will split the backup data across multiple files and does not cause this error to occur

`COPY my_keyspace_name.my_table_name TO 'cassandra_dump/my_keyspace_name.my_table_name.csv' WITH HEADER=true AND PAGETIMEOUT=40 AND MAXOUTPUTSIZE=100000 AND DELIMITER='|';`